# blueimp github file uploader IE maxFileSize issue

Tags: jquery, file-upload, blueimp

In IE the maxFileSize setting is not supported. But, in the demo http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/ the error 'File too big' is getting displayed on click of 'Start' button when uploading a big file. Could I know how it is getting accomplished, please?

Answer (score 0):

on the server side you can see the filesize(if you use PHP it's in  `$_FILES["files"]["size"]`) and send an error message.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I had set the max sizes in the main.js file in the js/ directory, but on IE it did not work.

To make it work on Internet Explorer, I also had to set max sizes in UploadHandler.php in the server/php/ directory of the plugin.

Originally it said
            'max_file_size' => null,
, which I changed into
            'max_file_size' => 1000000,